# Chartjs lines with two stacked lines are not displaying y-axis values ​correctly

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to create a js chart with lines that, when they have the same value, are not above each other, but when adding stacked: true, the values ​​on the y axis are incorrect

```
const yValues1 = [751, 1300, 1700, 1500, 2550, 3634];
const yValues2 = [750, 2300, 2700, 2890, 2550, 3634]; 

const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
    pointRadius: 0,
    pointHitRadius: 0,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: '2023',
        data: yValues2,
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: '#2196F3', // Cor da borda para o segundo dataset
      },
      {
        label: '2022',
        data: yValues1,
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: '#EF6C00', // Cor da borda para o primeiro dataset
      },
    ]
  },
  options: {
    interaction: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: true,
    },
    stacked: false,
    pointBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
    tension: 0.4,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
        },
    tooltip: {
         caretPadding: 60,
       backgroundColor: '#fef1ed',
       usePointStyle: false,
       titleColor: 'black',
       displayColors: false,
       titleMarginBottom: 5,
       titleFont: {
         size: 14,
       },
       borderWidth: 1,
       bodyColor: 'black',
       yAlign: 'bottom',
       //xAlign:'right',
       callbacks: {
         title: (context) => {
  // Obtém o valor do ponto atual
  const value = context[0].raw;

  // Formata o valor monetário com o símbolo da libra (£)
  const formattedValueWithSymbol = value.toLocaleString('en-GB', { style: 'currency', currency: 'GBP' });

  // Remove o símbolo da libra (£) do início do valor formatado
  const formattedValue = formattedValueWithSymbol.slice(1);

  // Retorna o valor formatado sem o símbolo da libra (£) no início
  return formattedValueWithSymbol;
         },
         label: (tooltipItem) => {
                    return ''
         },
       },
      //filter: function(tooltipItem, data) {
         //return tooltipItem.dataIndex !== 5
      //},
    },
      customBalloon: {
        backgroundColor: "#fef1ed",
      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        stacked: true,
        offset: true,
         ticks: {
            color: ['#000000'],
            font: {
              weight: (value) => {
              return value.index === 5 ? 'bold' : 'normal'
              }
            },
            padding: 20
          },
        grid: {
          drawOnChartArea: false,
        },
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true,
        beginAtZero: true,
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Values',
         },
         border: {
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
            stepSize: 750,
        }
      }
    },
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: true
  },
  plugins: [customBalloon]
}

// Criando o gráfico
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, options);
```

with stacked
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9Umq.png)

no stacked
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyA9m.png)

How to adjust this?

I hope to have lines that stay on the graph and are not above each other with equal values ​​and the y axis has the correct values

Comment: If y axis is `stacked`, the values of the second dataset are considered to start from the values of the first one, that is, the distance from the x axis is the sum of the values; thus the y values are correct (750+751, 1300+2300, etc.).

Comment: If you want to avoid the artifacts of smoothing that place one curve under the other between points of equal value, you should set (the default) `tension: 0`; otherwise, any kind of smoothing would create that effect with the data you posted. You may set the value of `tension` per dataset, so you can play with those values for a one-off chart that looks as you want, but the only solution that works in general is `tension: 0`.

Comment: Could you show me an example please? I don't know if you understood my question correctly, the problem is not with the tension.

Comment: Your [code](https://jsfiddle.net/dy86bav2/) with tension: blue under red for Mai-Jun; your [code](https://jsfiddle.net/dy86bav2/1/) with `tension: 0`, overlap red-blue for Mai-Jun.

Comment: I don't want the lines to be on top of each other, I want them to be on top of each other, very close together, I showed the example. Changing ternsion doesn't change anything

Comment: You should clarify what is the intended result. You may try `cubicInterpolationMode: "monotone"` ([docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#cubicinterpolationmode)) if it fits what you want to achieve; apart from that, the value of `tension`, and the actual values (x, y) of the points, there is nothing else that influences the way the curves are drawn.